# mod_rewrite configuration for apache results in 404 error page

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

I am getting a 404 error when I reload the page of my MERN stack project hosted on an Apache2 server. I tried to solve it by altering the configuration files like I found in an answer on SO. But the problem is that solution was specific to either Tomcat or httpd. Can anyone give me a solution for Apache2

I tried to edit the JavaScript .conf file present in the apache2 directory but it didn't work, then I made a new file named apache2.conf directly in apache2 directory and pasted this code but it also didn't work:

```xml
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```